# how to use nautilus for ftps locations in 18.04.4 bionic

Tags: nautilus, ftp, transfer

when trying to access an ftps server with *username* and *password*
I entered my url as nautilus location in the described format

```
ftps://user@server.name.xyz
```

this however, does **not yield** the expected result of a **password prompt**.

instead the **connection attempt** seems to take ages and nautilus **remains busy**.

only the push of the cancel button is left.

**no connection** is instantiated

- is this protocol supposed to work? (it is at least mentioned in the help pop-up)
- how do I get it to work?

**NOTE:** the *server is working fine*, and filezilla can connect without problems

thanks

Comment: @Terrance, thanks, but I am _not interested in configuring an ftps server_. the server is up and running somewhere, and it works properly.

Comment: Is the gvfs-backends package installed? what is the output of `dpkg -L gvfs-backends | grep /ftp` ?

Comment: @steeldriver You are probably correct on your question there.  I tested it fully from mine to another server I have here and ssl made a difference, but I got instant errors when when I connected on NO and worked on YES, but I do have the gvfs-backends installed on my host.  I am removing my comments.

Comment: @steeldriver : I got
    /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-ftp
    /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-sftp
    /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/ftp.mount
    /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/ftps.mount
    /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/sftp.mount

Comment: OK that seems to be in order - what happens if you use `ftp://...` in place of `ftps://`?

Comment: @steeldriver I will try, but then it probably wouldn't know about the default port number of the service (control lines 21 vs. 990)

Comment: You can specify the port at the end of the address.  `ftps://user@server.name.xyz:990`

Comment: @Terrance neither `ftp://` or `ftps://` w/ or w/o port 990 return a password prompt. behavior as initially described. filezilla works

Comment: You might have a bad installation of Nautilus then or a bug.  I have tested it here with FileZilla, Nautilus and a server running FTP with SFTP and FTPS and both the FTP and FTPS are working fine and prompt me every time for a username and password when using Nautilus.  I am also using 18.04.4 LTS.  Maybe try completely removing Nautilus then reinstall it.  If that doesn't help, file a bug on it.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for checking this. will do.